# Find the control point of quadratic Bezier curve having only the end-points

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, numerical-methods, bezier-curve

How to explicitly find the control point $C_0(x_0,y_0)$ of quadratic Bezier curve if I have only its end-points $C_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $C_2(x_2,y_2)$?

**Guess**

This should be done using the fact that the tangent passing through $C_1$ and $C_2$ meets at $C_0$. So, from $$y=m_1x+b_1~~ {\rm and}~~ y=m_2x+b_2,
$$ 
with
$$
m_1=\frac{y_0-y_1}{x_0-x_1},~~ m_2=\frac{y_0-y_2}{x_0-x_2},~~ b_1=y_1-m_1x_1,~~ b_2=y_2-m_2x_2.
$$
Therefore
$$
m_1x_0+b_1=m_2x_0+b_2~~ {\rm or}~~ x_0=\frac{b_2-b_1}{m_1-m_2},
$$
which is nothing else but identity. Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**

The end-points are located in an ellipse.

Comment: Do you have a parametric description such as $x= a t^3+..., y= c t^3+...$ ?

Comment: curve end point tangents meet  at cp.

Comment: From tangents I have $x_c=\frac{b_2-b_1}{m_1-m_2}$ and $y_c=m_1x_c+b_2$ with $m_1=\frac{y_c-y_1}{x_c-x_1}$ and $m_2=\frac{y_c-y_2}{x_c-x_2}$. How to find $b_1$ and $b_2$??

Comment: Are they $b_1=y_1-m_1x_1$ and $b_2=y_2-m_2x_2$, correspondingly, or I will arrive at identity?

Comment: I`m arriving at identity.

Comment: Do you know the slopes at the end-points ($m_1$ and $m_2$)?

Comment: It turned out that both end-points are located on an ellipse. But does it define $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Comment: if you want the Bezier curve to match the ellipse, then you should get the tangent vectors from the ellipse. If you are willing to use a rational quadratic, rather than a regular polynomial quadratic, then you can match the ellipse exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Joriki says, you can't get the other control point with no other information.

However, if you know a point on the line you can work it out.  The formula for a quadratic Bezier function taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve is:

$P(t) = (1-t)^2P0 + 2(1-t)tP1 + t^2P2$

If you know any two control points, and a separate point on the line at a known time you can calculate the third control point.  Say you know the start and end points P0 and P2, and know the curve passes through P(0.5) at t=0.5:

$$
P(0.5) = (1-0.5)^2P0 + 2(1-0.5)0.5P1+0.5^2P2\\
P(0.5) = 0.25P0 + 0.5P1 + 0.25P2\\
P1 = 2P(0.5)-0.5P0 - 0.5P2
$$

For a cubic Bezier if you know the start and end points you can find the middle two control points using the method described here: https://web.archive.org/web/20131225210855/http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/html/bezier_interpolation.html

That requires you to know the points that the curve goes through at t=1/3 and t=2/3.  I'm afraid I haven't tried generalising it to any points in time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the control point from the end points. A quadratic Bézier curve is defined by all three points. If you have only the end points, you can arbitrarily choose a control point to define a quadratic Bézier curve.